# @AfterStep/@BeforeStep is not working for Cucumber Selenium Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am struggling @AfterStep/@Beforestep in cucumber selenium java project.

when i used @AfterStep cucumber hook it not executes that method(it skips that method)

I tried with many versions but still not luck.

Can anyone help me with latest versions POM file which has no compatibility issue

I put this file at stepDefinition and using cucumber.api.java.AfterStep

```
    @AfterStep
public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) throws IOException, JiraException 
{
   System.out.println("in step method");
   if (scenario.isFailed()) {
   System.out.println("in failes screen");
   File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
   String path=null;
   path=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\target\\Screenshot\\"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png";
   FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(path));
   Reporter.addScreenCaptureFromPath(path);
   Reporter.addStepLog(scenario.getId());
  }
}
```

TestRunner:

```
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
features = {"src/extentPackage/LoginToABSi.feature"},
glue = {"stepDefinitions"},
plugin = {"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/report.html"}
)
public class RunCukesTest {

     public static WebDriver driver;
     public static WebDriverWait wait;
     public static ExtentProperties extentProperties;

@AfterClass
public static void teardown() {

Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("Report-Config/extent-config.xml"));
Reporter.setSystemInfo("user", System.getProperty("user.name"));
Reporter.setSystemInfo("os", "Mac OSX");
Reporter.setTestRunnerOutput("Sample test runner output message");

}
```

Comment: Share us with more informations like your runner class please.

Comment: Are the hook classes included in the glue option?

Comment: hi Grasshopper, i new to cucumber may i know in brief about it. Means how to add it how to make hook classes for it.

Comment: Selçuk Ayhan, I have added code

Comment: @Shashi Is the hook class contained in the "stepdefinitions" package?

Comment: @Grasshopper yes it contained

Comment: @Grasshopper AFAIK cucumber doesn't have `@BeforeStep` and `@AfterStep` annotations. These are JUnit's. Are you sure you can combine those two?

Comment: @Fenio are sure these 2 tags are not belongs to cucumber. but we can import library files for same it allows to add

Comment: @Shashi That doesn't mean the annotation will be respected by the runners

Comment: @Fenio check the code for these 2 annotations in cucumber java code - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/java/src/main/java/cucumber/api/java

Comment: @Shashi what is the cucumber version?

Comment: I apologies for delay in reply..

Comment: Cucumber version is 4+

Comment: @Sashi what package is '@tearDown' method in?

Comment: I have used import cucumber.api.Scenario;
import cucumber.api.java.AfterStep;

Comment: @Fenio If i used Gherkin 4.1.3 AfterStep works but we have to comment plugin code i.e. plugin = {"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:./Cucumber-Reports/Cucumber-Report.html","rerun:target/rerun.txt"}. So if i used AfterStep then unable to create extent report. If i used extentreport plugin it throws error i.e. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:gherkin/formatter/reporter